# Port forwarding via Watchguard

Tags: port-forwarding, oracle, watchguard

I have problem with accessing oracle database with oracle SQL developer.

I'm using Watchguard m400 as my firewall/router and Windows Server 2012 R2 as Oracle DB Server.

I have server with local IP, lets say its 10.10.10.10, I NATted it with s-nat to a global IP one, let's say 210.210.210.210. I added a policy with ports 3389 - RDP and 1521 - oracle. I can RDP to that server's global IP (210.210.210.210) from local network or from public one, but unfortunatelly I can't acces via Oracle SQL Developer to that server at global IP (it works only from local network to local IP). Of course, on server I have oppened 3389 + 1521 in Windows Firewall.

Any ideas?

My s-nat looks like this:
From Any to 210.210.210.210 -> 10.10.10.10 Policy with ports 3389, 1521

Regards.

Comment: Almost certainly it needs other ports open, and following @learley's suggestions will help you find which ( maybe 'connection manager' on tcp 1630? ) - but regardless, this is bad idea to open things to the world, anyone could be brute forcing your Oracle server if you do this. Much more sensible would be to use the Watchguard's built in VPN support - SSL VPN or IPSEC VPN, and then give VPN users access to LAN services...

Answer (score 0):

Your rules seems correct as you have described it and as you say the RDP portion works so it seems to be defined correctly. In situations like this, I will generally turn on logging for the policy (default settings only log deny packets for a packet filter) and attempt the connection again with the application to confirm that the traffic is actually flowing as expected. Sometimes, the application will be attempting to connect on a port or service I was not expecting, or there is some routing/DNS/application configuration issue preventing the traffic from reaching the firewall in the first place.

You can get a live view using the Traffic Monitor feature in either the Watchguard Web UI or via the Firebox System Manager software. Watch the Traffic Monitor and attempt a connection. If you are getting a lot of log traffic at the time, it can also help to filter by your source IP address.

Traffic Monitor reference for Web UI: http://www.watchguard.com/help/docs/fireware/11/en-US/index.html#en-US/system_status/traffic_monitor_web.html